# jQuery: dialog() of table data from ajax not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
$(function () {
    $('.referral').on('click', function () {
        $('#hold').html($(this).find('DIV').html());
        $('#hold').dialog();
    });
});

$(function getTableData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'interface_API.php',
        data: "",

        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                getTableData()
            }, 1000);
            var body = document.getElementById('tbody');
            body.innerHTML = '';
            for (var i in data) {
                var row = data[i];
                var customerCode = row.CustomerCode;
                var phone = row.PhoneNumber;
                var thetime = row.TimeStamp;

                var tr = document.createElement('TR');
                tr.className += " " + "referral";
                body.appendChild(tr);

                var td = document.createElement('TD');
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(customerCode));
                tr.appendChild(td);

                var td = document.createElement('TD');
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(phone));
                tr.appendChild(td);

                var td = document.createElement('TD');
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(thetime));
                tr.appendChild(td);

                var tr2 = document.createElement('TR');
                body.appendChild(tr2);

                var td2 = document.createElement('TD');
                var divE = document.createElement('DIV');
                divE.className += " " + "extra";
                var text = document.createTextNode("sage, extra, etc");
                divE.appendChild(text);
                td2.appendChild(divE);
                tr2.appendChild(td2);
            }

        }
    });
});
```

I have data from a JSON api that is imported using ajax.
This is displayed to a table, of which the rows are created using JS.

With each row, there is an additional row of 'additional' data that is hidden from the user.
on click of a row, i wish for a dialog to appear displaying this 'additional' data.

Initally i tryed todo this with writing out the rows in "raw format" (`var row = "<tr><td>...</td></tr>"` etc) however i read that this does not work well with javascript functions like the one i am trying to execute as the DOM has already been set (i'm not 100% sure about that). This is why i use JS to create each element & do it correctly, to some respect.

**However**, i am still unable to get the dialog to appear

Notes.
below the table (html hard coded) is a empty div which is used as a holder for when a dialog is to appear.

I have had success before when the data is static & ajax is not involved

Comment: i can confirm that the ajax/json data is correct

Comment: Are you including jquery-ui in your page?

Comment: yup, 1.9.2/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css 

aswell as the .min

Comment: As 2 seperate tasks, the ajax to table works just fine. and the dialog from table works just fine. Its just this combo of dialog from table from ajax that is causing an issue

Comment: Have you stepped through it to see where it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
It seems that the JS `.on('click', function()` was not being called, or registered at the right point. i checked on the DOM properties using chrome dev tools & `.referral`'s onclick property was null.

Instead, i set the `onclick` attribute of each `<TR>` with the function `clicks()` like so:

```
var tr = document.createElement('TR');
tr.setAttribute("onclick", "clicks(this)");
```

With,

```
function clicks(param){
        $('#hold').html($(param).find('DIV').html());
        $('#hold').dialog();
};
```